# How can I view Image Dimensions in Finder List View?

Tags: finder

How do I view image dimensions in List View in Finder? I found [this](http://osxdaily.com/2011/05/18/show-image-dimensions-in-mac-os-x-finder-windows-desktop/) but I don't find this option on my machine. I'm running Snow Leopard; is this a Lion only feature?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about 10.6, but on 10.7 the dimensions are shown in information panels:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Lion only

Any subdirectory of `~/Pictures` can do this:

[image]

**Note:** (Thanks to @koiyu)

While the first nine options are available for any list view, the options below the first line differ according to the relative location in your folder.

Options in:`~/Pictures/..` Options in:`~/Music/..`

[image]
[image]

Comment: [If I remember correctly](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/32043/1453) the extra columns available for list view are relative to the folder path. Is your `Mac Wallpaper` under `~/Pictures` by any chance? If not, I stand corrected.

Comment: Interesting! Your assumption is correct. I did not notice this before because I sort my media according to the default folders in the home directory.

Comment: Is this available only in Lion ?

Comment: I think this is available in Snow Leopard aswell, but I cannot confirm this. Try it and report back!

Comment: I definitely dont see dimensions listed anywhere for column view format.

Comment: Ok, I'll add this info to my answer.