# Where and how are the extra columns available for list view in Finder defined?

Tags: macos, finder

In an [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/32043/1453) to an [earlier question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/18728/1453) I found out that the available columns for Finder's list view are relative to the folder path. This means that one could choose to add a `Dimensions` column when browsing under `~/Pictures` or `Artist` under `~/Music` or `Codec` under `~/Movies`.

*Where* and *how* these are defined?

Is there a centralised file that links a path `~/Pictures`, column `Dimensions` and action "`get file's dimensions`" together?

Or is the column and the action defined in a centralised location and then a folder's property (like "`this is a folder for pictures`") enables the columns?

Or are these all defined relatively under the folder path? Or something else?

I think I'm indirectly asking whether or not it is possible to customise the columns (add own) and enable them for different locations.

Answer (score -1):

Try renaming the folder to "Pictures" or moving it into a folder named "Pictures" -- that did the trick for me.

Comment: This does not answer the question, where the association between the folder name and the columns is specified.