# How to show width and height of image files in Finder's column view?

Tags: snow-leopard, finder, graphics

Is there any way to view the width and height of image type files in Finder's column view?

**I am runnning Snow Leopard.**

There isn't a checkbox for dimension in the Finder's view options:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Icon View** and **Column View**

Pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or *Right Clicking*, while in the folder where the pictures are, will show the *Options* menú. Then **Show View Options**, and enable **Show Item Info**. This will show the image's dimensions below the file.

You could press *Use as Default*, if, well, you want it to be default.

**List View**

While in **List view** , by *Right Clicking* the list's title bar, you'll be able to choose extra information columns to show. As Koiyu explains [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/32043/21487):

> The list of extra columns is relative to the folder's location. In order to get the dimensions available, the folder in question has to reside somewhere under ~/Pictures/. (Under ~/Music/ you could choose e.g. artist or album and under ~/Movies/ you could choose length or codecs and so on…)

Comment: This is exactly what I need: show the Dimension column in the finder using list view. What you say only work in Icon view, I need to have the rest of columns, then I need to use List view.

Comment: Edited the answer to match you needs.

Comment: I moved a image file under Picture but I the 'dimension' column is not visible yet. Look the capture I upload at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Apparently the List View thing will only work for Lion. The Column and List view, though, should work on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't see the picture before. It shows that you are doing Cmd+J, but have you tried Right Clicking the list's bar? If you click, it will show more options. To make it clear, I mean Right Clicking on "Kind", for instance.

Comment: Nothing happens if I right-click the list bar. I guess it is a lion feature

Comment: Was pretty sure about it, but better safe than sorry. I'll keep searching.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to List View (Cmd + 2) and then back to Column View (Cmd + 3). This helps me, sometimes there's just "–" but this fiddle brings numbers back.

Comment: works for me on later versions of osx (2015)

Answer (score 0):

The information panels (⌘I) should also show the dimensions for most image files.

[image]

Comment: this is what I usually do but it is time wasting though.

Answer (score 0):

Much better is cmd+alt+i and move on all files for quick view dimesnions.