# View info about PNG files

Tags: macos, graphics

I have a bunch of PNG files and I want to be able to:

- tell their pixel size
- preview them
- their file size

very quickly. Literally, right click and bang!

Any ideas?

What would also be handy would a way to tell their colors. So if I opened an image, it was easy to see that part of it was #4545AA for example.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `file` command in the Terminal also gives you some information:

```
% file foo.png 
foo.png: PNG image data, 612 x 792, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a peek at [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52269/how-to-show-width-and-height-of-image-files-in-finders-column-view) for some more details, but you can use the finder without having to install software to achieve most of this.

Basically, you can set your finder view to show dimensions as well as file size (and the usual, modified date etc), and you can set the thumbnail size for some preview, and simply hit space to open larger previews using quicklook.  Hitting Option+i on any file can get you extended info in addition.

I'm not sure about your exact requirements for colours, but a combination of a quicklook preview with Color Picker running (built in app) should be one way of achieving this also.